# higlight word where text pointer is

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement one of sublime text functionality in javascript. When you press CTRL+D in Sublime and you don't have a word highlighted it directly highlight the word the text pointer is the nearest to.

Do you have any idea how you could do that in javascript? I'm using jQuery.

Here's is what I'm doing in javascript but it doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/fsgK6/1/

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var start = $('textarea').prop("selectionStart");
    var end = $('textarea').prop("selectionEnd");
    if(start == end && start != 0){
        var textarea_text = $('textarea').val();
        var word = "";
        // left side
        while($.trim(word) == word){
            start = start - 1;
            word = textarea_text.substr(start, end - start);
            if(start == 0)
                break;
        }
        word = $.trim(word);
        // right side
        while($.trim(word) == word){
            end = end + 1;
            word = textarea_text.substr(start, end - start);
            if(end > textarea_text.length)
                break;
        }
        word = $.trim(word);

        $('textarea').prop('selectionStart') = start;
        $('textarea').prop('selectionEnd') = end;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').prop('selectionStart') = start;
$('textarea').prop('selectionEnd') = end;
```

should be

```
$('textarea').prop('selectionStart', start);
$('textarea').prop('selectionEnd', end);
```

as for the selection start and end.. it looks like you need to look closer at how you are detecting word boundaries

i ended up adjusting the start code to more like this (and changed to `textarea` click for testing):

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
    var start = $('textarea').prop("selectionStart");
    var end = $('textarea').prop("selectionEnd");
    console.log(start + ' ' + end);
    if(start == end && start != 0){
        var textarea_text = $('textarea').val();
        var word = "";
        // left side
        while($.trim(word) == word){
            start = start - 1;
            word = textarea_text.substr(start - 1, end - start);
            console.log(word);
            if(start == 0)
                break;
        }
        word = $.trim(word);
        // right side
        while($.trim(word) == word){
            end = end + 1;
            word = textarea_text.substr(start, end - start);
            if(end > textarea_text.length)
                break;
        }
        word = $.trim(word);

        $('textarea').prop('selectionStart', start);
        $('textarea').prop('selectionEnd', end);
    }
})
```

heres an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fsgK6/2/

Answer (score 0):

I've done it and it works, here is the code: https://gist.github.com/mimoo/9907534